# Initializing a C# IntPtr to accept data from unmanaged C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have an exported function in unmanaged C++ code that expects a pointer to a BStr, where it will write some text data (258 bytes, max)

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int CppFunc(BSTR *data)
{ ... }
```

I want that data as a string.

This works

```
[DllImport( ... CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int CppFunc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string data);
```

but it creates a memory leak.

I assume what I should be doing is creating and passing an IntPtr, then Marshal out the Bstr as a string, then free the IntPtr:

```
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(512);
CppFunction(p);
string data = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(p);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p) ;
```

The problem is, with that code, I get a System.AccessViolationException on the call into Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(p).

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: but what are you doing inside `CppFunc` with `BSTR*`

Comment: "expects a pointer to a BStr, where it will write some text data (258 bytes, max)" seems rather unlikely given the signature.  To do that, it would only need `BSTR`, which already contains a pointer.  The most likely thing with `BSTR*` is that the function will call `AllocSysString` and store the resulting `BSTR` to your pointer.  Can you double-check the documentation and see if this is accurate?

Comment: It is not a function that returns data, other the the int, the parameter is not BSTR**.  Writing into the BSTR breaks the contract and is expected to corrupt memory, quite unlikely it does that.  Talk  to whomever gave you this function definition about how you are supposed to use it.

Comment: *It is not a function that returns data* ... yes, it is ... obviously because `typedef WCHAR* BSTR;` now you can call it like `BSTR test; CppFunc(&test);` and inside  `CppFunc` `*test= ::AllocSysString(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the Remarks for [`Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringbstr?view=netframework-4.7.2) is

> Call this method only on strings that were allocated with the unmanaged SysAllocString and SysAllocStringLen functions.

Which is probably where your crash came from.

Add to this your C++ function expects `BSTR*` (effectively a pointer to a pointer to the first character of data in the string), but you pass it a pointer to data.

Remember that a BSTR has a special structure: it starts with 4 bytes of length, then data, then a null. The pointer points to the first character of *data*. So `Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR` is looking *backwards* from the pointer to find the length of the string - but that isn't memory which was allocated by `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.

---

It could be that your C++ function does something like `*data = ....AllocSysString();` - that is, it never reads the string it's given, but instead assigns the pointer to a string which it allocates.

In that case, you probably want something like:

```
[DllImport( ... CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int CppFunc(out IntPtr data);

...

CppFunc(out IntPtr p);
string data = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(p);
Marshal.FreeBSTR(p) ;
```

Here, we pass it a pointer to a pointer. The C++ function re-assigns the pointer to point to the first character of data in a BSTR, and we use that to deserialize the BSTR, and then free it (using a method which knows how to free BSTRs).

---

If this isn't the case, it's unclear why your C++ function takes a `BSTR*` (as opposed to a `BSTR`), and what it does with it. I think we need to see that before much else can be said.

If your C++ function took a `BSTR` instead (remember that `BSTR` is itself a pointer), then what you should be doing is using a `StringBuilder` (with a particular initial capacity) - the marshalling layer turns that into a pointer the C++ code can write to, and then you can turn the `StringBuilder` into a string.

```
[DllImport( ... CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int CppFunc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] StringBuilder data);

...

var data = new StringBuilder(512); 
CppFunction(data);
string result = data.ToString();
```

Comment: That is not compatible with a `BSTR*` argument.

Comment: @Ben good point, I missed that it was a pointer, thanks. Updated my answer.

Comment: @canton7 That was it and the code change you suggested ("you probably want...") fixed it. Thank you.